# Перенос приложения freeGLUT на другую машину

Tags: linux, opengl, gcc, g++

Использую обе i686 Linux машины, на первой установлен freeglut3 и freeglut3-dev, на второй специально не ставил эти пакеты чтобы протестировать переносимость на другие машины.

Итак на первой машине на которой установлены пакеты freeGLUT компилирую так: 
`g++ main.c -lglut -lGL -lGLU -o test`
компилируется хорошо и исправно запускается. Переношу на другую машину (котрая без пакетов), при запуске пишет

> error while loading shared libraries: libglut.so.3: cannot open shared
>   object file: No such file or directory

Также пробовал добавить флаг `--static` в pkg-config так: `` g++ main.cpp -lglut -lGL -lGLU -o `pkg-config --static --cflags --libs` test `` но все равно таже ошибка при запуске.

вот файл: https://pastebin.com/dV53ZRnY

Вопрос: Как скомпилировать чтобы все необходимые библиотеки 
унаследовались в папку с проектом или вкомпилировались в сам файл?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала при вызове **pkg-config** надо обязательно указывать название пакета, чьи флаги вы хотите получить. Эта утилита выводит на свой stdout параметры, которые нужно передать компилятору или компоновщику. Конструкция из акцентов (`` `...` ``) заставляет оболочку **bash** выполнить содержащуюся внутри неё команду и подставить её вывод на место аргументов в объемлющей команде.

Поэкспериментируйте, и посмотрите, что выдаст такая команда:

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs gl
```

Добавьте флаг `--static`, и вывод команды станет чуть более обширным из-за того, что для статической компоновки нужно знать, где искать определения всех используемых функций даже тех, что вызываются из подключаемых библиотек.

К сожалению, в старых версиях **glut** не было файла .pc — пакета для **pkg-config**. Поэтому эта утилита ничего про **glut** не знает. Судя по всему, у вас какой-то Debian-подобный дистрибутив, в его репозиториях пока нету библиотеки freeglut третьей версии.

В качестве обходного шага можно рассмотреть распространение вашей программы вместе с файлом `libglut.so.3`. Этот файл можно скопировать из системного каталога. Компоновать программу придётся с опцией `-rpath`, вот так:

```
g++ main.cpp -Wl,-rpath,. -lGL -lglut
```

Ещё один из вариантов: таки воспользоваться новой версией glut. В ArchLinux её можно взять из репы, в Debian придётся повозиться и скомпилировать её самостоятельно (на [официальном сайте](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/index.php#download) довольно подробная инструкция). Новая версия также распространяется с пакетом для **pkg-config** (это файл .pc), и тут уже не должно возникнуть проблем. Просто пропишите этой утилите имена используемых вами библиотек: `gl` и `glut`.

Но на самом деле, на мой взгляд, лучшим способом было бы задать все зависимости вашей программы и устанавливать их в рабочей системе. Правда, такое не всегда бывает возможно.